# How to create hint inside dropdown menu which is not disappear?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create the same dropdown menu design as in the screenshot, I have already created a dropdown menu, but the tooltip is not inside the dropdown menu, but at the top. How can you create the same design? Or do I need to write something custom? The main goal is to have hint inside dropdown and hint should not disappear when user chooses some value from drop down[image]

My current code looks like this:

```
 DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
            icon: SvgPicture.asset(
              R.ARROW_DOWN,
              width: 24,
              height: 24,
            ),
            items: widget.selectedProducts.map((String item) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: item,
                child: Text(
                  item,
                  style: context.fonts.semiBold16.copyWith(color: context.colors.darkGray),
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (String? value) => widget.onChangedProduct,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              filled: true,
              label: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  text: widget.productHintDropDown,
                  style: context.fonts.regular14.copyWith(color: context.colors.darkGray),
                  children: <InlineSpan>[
                    TextSpan(
                      text: context.loc.asterisk,
                      style: context.fonts.regular16.copyWith(color: context.colors.red),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              fillColor: context.colors.inversedSecondaryText,
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: context.colors.lightGray, width: 2),
              ),
              floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
              disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: context.colors.lightGray, width: 2),
              ),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: context.colors.lightGray, width: 2)),
            ),
          ),
```